# Parent component unnecessarily re-rendering child on parent state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a simple Magic The Gathering search engine. The vision is to have a list of search results, and when a search result is clicked the main display renders extended information about the card selected.

[You can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1DOJ.jpg)

The top level `App` component contains the state of what card is to be displayed and the `ScrollView` component maintains the state of the card selected for only the highlighting of the selected card in the list. I propagate down the `setDisplayCard` handler so that when a card is clicked in the list, I can set the display card as a callback.

```jsx
function App(props) {

  const [displayCard, setDisplayCard] = useState(null)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchDisplay handleCardSelect={setDisplayCard}/>
      <CardDisplay card={displayCard} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```jsx
function SearchDisplay({handleCardSelect}) {

    const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const cards = await testCardSearch();
            setCards(cards);
        })();
    }, []);

    async function handleSearch(searchTerm) {
        const searchCards = await cardSearch({name: searchTerm});
        setCards(searchCards)
    };

    return (
        <StyledDiv>
            <SearchBar 
                handleSubmit={handleSearch}
            />
            <ScrollView 
                handleCardSelect={handleCardSelect} 
                cards={cards}
            />
        </StyledDiv>
    );
}
```

```jsx
function ScrollView({cards, handleCardSelect}) {

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

    return (
        <ViewContainer>
            {cards.map((card, idx) =>
                <li 
                    key={idx} 
                    style={selected === idx ? {backgroundColor: "red"} : {backgroundColor: "blue"}}
                    onClick={() => {
                        setSelected(idx);
                        handleCardSelect(card);
                    }}
                >
                    <Card card={card} />
                </li>
            )}
        </ViewContainer>
    );
}
```

The issue I am having is that calling `setDisplayCard` re-renders my `ScrollView` and eliminates its local state of the card that was selected so I am unable to highlight the active card in the list. Based on my understanding of react, I don't see why `ScrollView` re-renders as it does not depend on the state of `displayCard`. And I am not sure what approach to take to fix it. When I click on a card in the list, I expect it to highlight red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child component's `render` method will always be called, once its parent's render method is invoked. The same goes for if its props or state change.

Since you're using functional components, you could use the [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) HOC to prevent unnecessary component re-renders.

`React.memo` acts similar to a `PureComponent` and will shallowly compare `ScrollView`'s old `props` to the new `props` and only trigger a re-render if they're unequal:

```
export default React.memo(ScrollView);
```

`React.memo` also has a second argument, which gives you control over the comparison:

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  // only update if a card was added or removed
  return prevProps.cards.length === nextProps.cards.length;
}

export default React.memo(ScrollView, areEqual);
```

If you were to use class-based components, you could use the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) life cycle method as well.

Comment: Thank you. I thought all components operated like PureComponents. I did not think that a parent render always required children render.

Answer (score 2):

By default (stateless) components re-render under 3 conditions

1. It's props have changed
2. It's state has changed
3. It's parent re-renders

This behavior can be changed using either `shouldComponentUpdate` for components or `memo` for stateless-components.

```
// If this function returns true, the component won't rerender
areEqual((prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.cards === nextProps.card)

export default React.memo(ScrollView, areEqual);
```

---

However I don't think this is your problem. You are using an array Index `idx` as your element key which can often lead to unexpected behavior.

Try to remove `key={idx}` and check if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score -2):

So your App component is supposed to hold the state of the card the user clicked? Right now your App component is stateless. It's a functional component. Try converting it to a class component with an initial, and maintained, state.

What is the logic of your setDisplayCard()?

I've heard that in React 16? there is something like 'useState()' and 'hooks', but I'm not familiar with it.

This person seemed to be having a similar problem,

[React functional component using state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821699/react-functional-component-using-state)

Comment: `useState()` is in `App()`. It turns a functional component into a statful component.

Comment: Ok, is the CardDisplay component supposed to exclusively be for showing the "more details" card on the side? Also, when you click the card and everything refreshes, are you even seeing 'CardDisplay' component rendered? Based on how react works, when the state changes, the function or class re-renders. So because you change the state of 'App', it re-renders 'SearchDisplay' which re-renders 'ScrollView'. 'ScrollView' would also need to know which card was selected if you wanted to highlight that card in the scroll while displaying its "more details" to the right.